# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, terminal

I downloaded an angular template and when running "ng serve" I receive:

> Cannot find module '@angular/compiler' Error: Cannot find module
>   '@angular/compiler'  ...

Then I tried everything that came up on google, including looking at the dependencies and reinstalling everything.

Then on uninstalling npm using this command:

```
sudo npm uninstall angular-cli
```

I get:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone
>   --depth=1 -q -b fix-drag-issue git://github.com/swimlane/dragula.git /Users/angellolazar/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-c0a842b4
>   /Users/angellolazar/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-c0a842b4/.git:
>   Permission denied
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
> at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
> at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:600:12)
> ```
>
> ⸨            ░░░░░░⸩ ⠹ extract:npm: sill extract strip-ansi@3.0.1

Now, when looking at my version of Angular, I receive:

> Angular:  ... animations, cdk, common, compiler, core, forms,
>   http ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
>   ... router

It's a mess... Please let me know what other information you may need to get this resolved.

Comment: Unless you installed globally, you should be able to just delete the folder where you attempted to install. Then you should be able to start over.

Answer (score 0):

I think by uninstalling everything, they mean to remove your node_modules folder and just install all your dependencies again. So just delete your node_modules folder and do an `npm install`.